# Static array, C++

Tags: c++, static

Edit: Sorry for this question, really don't know what I was asking for. Stackoverflow does not allow me to delete this question lol. If a mod sees this, please just delete.

Here's a "minimized" version of the code I'm having problems with:

```
class Texture {
};
class MyClass {
    static Texture Image;
};

int main() {
    vector<MyClass> Zombies; // The array Increases in the program
    MyClass Player;

    return 0;
}
```

So my problem seems to be that the two objects uses the same texture, I know that's how `static` works, but I don't know how I can make a static that just covers up each array.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking here...  And I'm not sure what that code demonstrates!  (I'm not sure it would even compile...)

Comment: So you are using static, know what it does, and are wondering how to make it not do that? Simple — don't use it.

Comment: I don't understand your post. Can you clarify what the problem you are having looks like. For example, do the two objects have different textures? Did want a single texture? Did you want multiple textures? What library did you find Texture from?

Comment: Two different classes? templatize the class? then you could instantiate it with a different dummy in each array? I don't even know if i'm speaking real C++ here

Comment: it dosent compile, it was just so you could get an idea what im having trouble with

Comment: sorry guys its my first question...

Comment: [It compiles fine](http://ideone.com/WlRuNH). For those who wander, `static class Texture Image` is legal in C++.

Comment: Is the idea to have one Texture for all the zombies and a second texture for the player?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want one texture for the entire array of Zombies and another texture for Player.

There's no way to do this automatically - your choices are to have all instances of the class share a single `static` member, or have each object contain its own.

If you break out the texture separately and have the objects contain a reference or pointer instead, you can share the texture objects that way. It will be up to you to initialize the reference or pointer in the constructor of each object.